# PyTorch and torchvision compiled with different versions. How to solve?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

PyTorch and Torchvision were compiled with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA `version=11.6` and torchvision `CUDA Version 11.3`. Please reinstall the torchvision that matches your PyTorch install.

I've tried to reinstall torchvision so many times from the website as well as PyTorch and python.
I'm stuck I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: try conda install together so that it resolves dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade your torchvision to one compiled with CUDA 11.6:

```
pip install --upgrade torchvision>=0.12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116